# Magento 2 RequireJs sometimes not loading data-mage-init components

Tags: requirejs, magento2

Breakpoint in file mage/apply/main.js sometimes breaks on breakpoint and sometimes not breaking on breakpoint. As result data-mage-init components not always init. And not working.
Please help!

[main.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKplX.png)

Comment: Update: there is problem that if (!this.inited) is false. In requirejs after onScriptLoaded().

Comment: Can you please update the answer if you've solved the issue? I am facing the same issue.